# How to draw line pointing in compass bearing direction from point shapefile?

Tags: qgis

I captured waypoint data in the field including the compass azimuth when looking at some summits.

I want to use these waypoints, that I have now in Shapefile format, to draw line shapefiles that point in the compass azimuth that I defined for each waypoint.

Do you know an elegant solution for this problem?

Comment: Thank you! That was the elegant solution I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You can choose linear symbols and rotate them in the menu:

```
 style --> advanced --> rotation
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok to further the answer above what i use for indication of view points is:

Create a layer with points.  In properties of the layer, change to categorized and sperated each out into each point.  then manually go through each point changing to  arrow or other SVG marker.  then rotationg in the symbol slector....where you would change the size of the symbol

Hope this helps.  I can post pics if it is not clear.

Comment: Ahh, maybe I should have mentioned, that it is not only about drawing lines! I need to create line shapefiles. Thus, I think this solution wouldn't really help.