# QGIS Draw dynamically marker's heading from field in a postgres database

Tags: qgis, postgis, markers

General description:
I am using QGIS as quick visualization tool, where I make a "PostGIS" database layer and I see user generated events.
Table structure as follows:

```
Id   |   time_of_event  | position         | heading  |
int  |   timestamp      | geometry(Point ) | smallint |
```

Specific problem:
When I draw the position I draw it as point, I would like to draw it like so, if heading is = 0 or > 360, otherwise I would like to draw it as arrow.

I have read [How to draw line pointing in compass bearing direction from point shapefile](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83825/how-to-draw-line-pointing-in-compass-bearing-direction-from-point-shapefile) and [Scaling vector field marker arrow based on attribute?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/237977/scaling-vector-field-marker-arrow-based-on-attribute) but both of them are static.
And I couldn't figure out how to draw them based on a conditional, is this even possible?

P.S. I am using QGIS 3.2

Edit: so I made it display the proper direction:
[image]

However how can I make a conditional, when heading is null, display red dot?

Comment: use *Rule based* classification; e.g. define a rule for `heading = 0 OR heading = 360` and another for `heading > 0 AND heading < 360` with respective symbols. rotation can then be applied separately.

Comment: @ThingumaBob very stupid question, however in which menu do I find this "rule based classification"?

Comment: ,) I added all this as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the ***Rule-based* classification** for this.

Assuming `dir` is the field with the angle:

- in the layers *Symbology* tab, choose *Rule-based* in the uppermost dropdown menu:

  [image: ![enter image description here]
  [image]

  - double-click the first entry to define the rule and name it if you like.
    then enter `"dir" = 0 OR "dir" = 360` (or `"dir" IN (0, 360)`) in the `Filter` field (alternatively, you can open the `Expression builder` dialog to a GUI for function definitions):

    [image]
  - in the same menu, define your point symbol as you like
  - back in the rule overview, add a second rule (hit the green `+`) and define it:
     use either `"dir" > 0 AND "dir" < 360` or select the `Else` bullet to simply select all features not in the other rules:

    [image]
  - this time, define your arrow and specify the `dir` field values in the *Data defined override* menu for `Rotation`:

    [image]
- neatly done

Comment: Thank you , this is kindly simplified for "dummies", exactly what I needed. I marked it as the accepted answer!

Comment: @thefolenangel glad it helped! ...I used to write those things more compact, and I hate screenshots and the hussle with them being right on spot. but then, there's no better way to ensure reproducibility. ...and since you asked...,)